# find all gz file not empty

Tags: find, gzip, rsync

I'm desperately searching how to find in a directory all the gzip files that are not empty, the goal if to retrieve all the logs from a date thru ssh and to rsync them into a local directory, but i can get 10k files depending the date, and a lot of them are empty so i would like to sort them before making the rsync.

I know i can find all gz files like this:

```
ssh toto "find /logexport/proxies*/logs/ -type f -name '*20170511*.gz'" > test.txt
```

but i would like to sort them removing the empty one, if they werent gzip i could use:

```
! -size 0
```

for now i rsync all the files into a folder and then i sort them like this:

```
for f in ${FOLDER}/*; do
    if [[ $(gunzip -c $f | head -c1 | wc -c) == "0" ]]; then
              rm -f $f
    fi
done
```

Do u know how to combine the last command into the first one ?

The goal is to get thru ssh a list of all the gz file that contains data.

Answer (score 1):

If the gzip files have no additional header information, such as a file name, then all of the empty gzip files should be 20 bytes long.